# How XBMC synchronizes subtitles with the video timeline

Tags: python, time, synchronization, xbmc

I am trying to find a way to synchronize my XBMC script with the video being played.
My script needs to get the current time of the video being played and send it to some other server. This I made but have a problem getting the current time of the video being played.

XBMC Python function getTime() gives different values when the video is paused and playing.
For example  getTime() without pausing return 109 ms and after pausing 67. Why ?
There can be because of some internal buffering but I need a proof.

I think understanding how XBMC matches the subtitles with the video frame being rendered on the screen will resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is an interesting question. Please, don't hesitate to [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you find one.

Comment: I will but until now did not found anything.